# PhP Login forms won't work but registration works well, I suspect the header Location at first but seems not to be the problem

Tags: php, forms, validation

I'm making an account form that has both its login and registration form on a single page for a website, registration form works fine with database but I can't sign in with it.

here's the code for uaccount.php (my forms)

```
<form action="uregistration.php" method="post">
    <!--SIGN UP FORM HERE-->
    <h1>Create Account</h1>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name" required>
    <input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" required>
    <input type="email" id="email" name ="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <input type="date" id="birthdate" name="birthdate" placeholder="Birthdate" required>
    <input type="text" id="contact" name="contact" placeholder="Contact No." maxlength = "11" required>
    <select type= "text" id="gender" name="gender" placeholder="Gender" required>
        <option selected disabled> Select your gender </option>
        <option value="male">Male</option>
        <option value="female">Female</option>
        <option value="others">Others</option>
    </select>
<button type="submit" id="register" name= "register">Sign Up</button>
</form>
</div>

<a href="index.php"> <i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i> </a>
<form action= "uvalidation.php" method="post">
    <!--SIGN IN FORM HERE-->
    <h1> Sign in </h1>
    <input type="email" id="email" name ="email" placeholder="Email" required>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required>
    <a href ="#">Forgot your Password?</a>
    <button type="submit" id="login" name= "login">Sign In</button>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

here's the code for uregistration.php (registration form database connection)

```
<?php

session_start();
header('Location: uaccount.php');

$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($con, 'castro_rentals');

$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);
$birthdate = $_POST['birthdate'];
$contact = $_POST['contact'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];

$s = " SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($num == 1) {
    echo "Email already taken!";
}else{
    $reg = " insert into user
                            (firstname, lastname, email, password, birthdate, 
                            contact, gender) 
                    VALUES ('$firstname' , '$lastname' , '$email' , 
                            '$password' , '$birthdate' , '$contact' , 
                            '$gender')";
    mysqli_query($con, $reg);
    echo " Registration Successful!";
}
```

here's the code for uvalidation.php (login form database connection)

```
<?php
session_start();
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysqli_select_db($con, 'castro_rentals');

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = sha1($_POST['password']);

$s = " SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $s);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($num == 1) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}else{
    header('Location: uaccount.php');
}
```

and lastly, here's the code for index.php (where I want to redirect my page after validating the login)

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    
    <title> Home | Castro Rentals </title>
    
</head>
<body>
    Welcome!!
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried

- capitalizing letter L in location
- removing white spaces inside the header location:
- also removed the closing ?> php end tag

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!
This will also remove the unescaped character issue like a `'` in a text string.

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using `MD5()` or `SHA1()`. 
PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Comment: Did you check the PHP Error Log?

Comment: TYPO!! `button type="submit" id="register" name= "register">Sign Up</button>` missing a `<` before `button>`

Comment: You do not actually FETCH a result from your query that attempts to select the existing user, in the login process

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: This is probably not the problem, but note that using `&&` instead of `AND` in a SQL query [is deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_and) as of MySQL 8.0.17.

Comment: What does "can't sign in with it" mean? How far through the code do you get before it fails? Do you see any error messages?

Comment: @RiggsFolly there's no need for the OP to `fetch` the result from the query while they're using this "home brew" password method, because the query will either find one row or not find it. They will of course need it when they switch to a proper password hashing method.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thank you for all of your suggestions, will do them all! but I fixed the problem because I accidentally put sha(1) on my uvalidation.php, I removed that and now it works!

Comment: @rickdenhaan that was indeed not the problem but thank you! I'll keep that in mind! I fixed it by removing sha(1) on uvalidation.php! I forgot to remove it because I copied and pasted it from my uregistration.php

Comment: @droopsnoot everything works aside from my login page, when  I enter my credentials it just refreshes the page, but I fixed it by removing sha(1) on uvalidation.php! I forgot to remove it because I copied and pasted it from my uregistration.php

Answer (score -1):

I fixed it! I removed the sha(1) on uvalidation.php! I forgot to remove it because I copied and pasted it from my uregistration.php

my code before in (uvalidation.php):
`$email = $_POST['email']; $password = sha1($_POST['password']);`

my code after (uvalidation.php):
`$email = $_POST['email']; $password = ($_POST['password']);`

Comment: If that fixed the problem, surely that means you are storing passwords in plain text?